# c++ subclass access functions of parent class

Tags: c++, class, subclass

I have the following Class structure:

```
class WiFiHandler{
    public:
        void doWiFiStuff();
};

class Machine {
    public:
        void doSomething();
        WiFiHandler _wifiHandler;

};
```

Now the `WiFiHandler::doWiFiStuff()` receives a request which should trigger execution of `Machine::doSomething()`.
However the Methods of `Machine` are not known to `WifiHandler`

How does this Subclass `WiFiHandler` execute Methods of its "Motherclass"?

Comment: parent or mother are bad terms to describe a compositional relationship.

Comment: what would be a better term to describe this relationship?

Comment: If you don't want `WiFiHandler` and `Machine ` to be related at all via inheritance, you can add a member to `WiFiHandler` , which is pointer (or reference) to `Machine`. You can pass it during initialization, then use it to access public methods of `Machine`.

Comment: You need to let `WiFiHandler` know about the `Machine` that owns it, or give it a callback function to use.

Comment: Neither of those is a subclass of the other.

Comment: I used the better term.

Comment: @Christopher Perhaps using terms like `superclass`, `baseclass`  etc(only if applicable) will be more suitable.

Comment: Thought exercise for your design: *"How does this Subclass WiFiHandler execute Methods of its 'Motherclass'?"* -- how does this `WiFiHandler` object know that it **has** a "Motherclass"? How does it know that it is part of a `Machine` object? What if your program looked like `int main() { WiFiHandler handler; handler.doWiFiStuff(); }` where there are no `Machine` objects. What should `doWiFiStuff()` do if it receives the sort of request you're thinking of?

Answer (score 2):

As many design issues, there are many ways to achieve similar result, each with some advatages and disadvatages.

Other answers to your question mention good soultions.

I'd like to propose a different one, that might fit some systems.
**This solution might be good if the following 2 conditions (which are related) are met:**

1. `Machine` has multiple methods that `WiFiHandler` has to call.
2. `Machine` has a close association with `WiFiHandler` and it's OK from other design constraints that it will be dependent on it (despite the fact that it is contained by it).

In this case, `WiFiHandler` can hold a pointer to the `Machine` containing it.
In order to solve the problem of circular #includes, we can use a forward declaration.
Note that WiFiHandler.cpp includes Machine.h and thus can use any public method of `Machine` for its own implementation.

**Code example:**

```
// WiFiHandler.h:
class Machine;  // forward declaration
class WiFiHandler {
    Machine * m_pMyMachine;
public:
    WiFiHandler(Machine * pMyMachine) : m_pMyMachine(pMyMachine) {}
    void doWiFiStuff();
};
```

```
// Machine.h:
#include "WiFiHandler.h"
class Machine {
public:
    Machine() : _wifiHandler(this) {}
    void doSomething();
    WiFiHandler _wifiHandler;
};
```

```
// WiFiHandler.cpp:
#include "WiFiHandler.h"
#include "Machine.h"
void WiFiHandler::doWiFiStuff()
{
    m_pMyMachine->doSomething();
    // ...
}
```

```
// Machine.cpp:
#include "Machine.h"
void Machine::doSomething()
{
    // Do the machine stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those is a *subclass* or "parent" of the other - there is no inheritance.
The `WiFiHandler` is just a member of `Machine` and has no knowledge of any `Machine`'s existence.

You need to give the `WiFiHandler` something to call in that function, and it's usually useful to make this more general than a specific `Machine` instance.
For instance, a callback function:

```
class WiFiHandler{
    public:
        WiFiHandler(std::function<void()> fun) : doIt(fun) {}
        void doWiFiStuff() { doIt(); }
    private:
        std::function<void()> doIt;
};

class Machine {
    public:
        Machine() : _wifiHandler([this]() { doSomething(); }) {}
        void doSomething() {}
        WiFiHandler _wifiHandler;
};
```

This way, `WiFiHandler` doesn't need to care about changes to `Machine` or whether one exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change `doWiFiStuff()` to

```
template< class R, class... Args >
void doWiFiStuff(std::function<R(Args...)> thing_to_do, Args... args);
```

so you can pass any function along to be called.